# What is wrong with below C++ regex code to extract names and value?

Tags: c++, regex

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "foo:12,bar:456,b:az:0,";
    regex c("(.*[^,]):([0-9]+),");
    smatch sm;
    if(regex_search(s, sm, c)) {
        cout << "match size:"<<sm.size()<<endl;
        for(int i=0; i < sm.size();i++){
            cout << "grp1 - " << sm[i] << "\tgrp2 - " << sm[i+1] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to extract names and corresponding value, I wrote following code but I get following output

```
match size:3
grp1 - foo:12,bar:456,b:az:0,   grp2 - foo:12,bar:456,b:az
grp1 - foo:12,bar:456,b:az      grp2 - 0
grp1 - 0        grp2 -
```

I expected it to be following

```
match size:3
grp1 - foo,   grp2 - 12
grp1 - bar    grp2 - 456
grp1 - b:az   grp2 - 0
```

Comment: I can highly recommend https://regex101.com/ to debug stuff like this.

Comment: It appears you are trying to use regex as a parser.   You might want to consider using a parser instead, like Boost [Spirit X3](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/index.html).

Comment: [`([^:]+):([0-9]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/4hGO7p/1) won't work. And this parsing logic won't either, because `:` can be part of the key.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi I was using https://regexr.com/6bu5s and it seemed to work

Comment: Shoot I realised that I had `*` in different place

Comment: @PeteBecker : but names can contain `:` also so that makes it little complex isn't it ? I thought regex could be easier , isn't it ?

Comment: @ART -- <shrug> -- copy to the first delimiter, a `:` followed by a digit. Regular expressions give you a high-level abstraction that often results in write-only code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confuse multiple match extraction with capturing group values retrieval from a single match (yilded by the `regex_search` function). You need to use a regex iterator to get all matches.

Here, `match size:3` means you have the whole match value (Group 0), a capturing group 1 value (Group 1, the `(.*[^,])` value) and Group 2 value (captured with `([0-9]+)`).

Also, the `.*` at the start of your pattern grabs as many chars other than line break chars as possible, so you actually can't use your pattern for multiple match extraction.

See [this C++ demo](https://ideone.com/Wt7uM8):

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "foo:12,bar:456,b:az:0,";
    regex c("([^,]+?):([0-9]+)");
    int matches = 0;
    smatch sm;
    sregex_iterator iter(s.begin(), s.end(), c); std::sregex_iterator end;   
    while(iter != end) { 
        sm = *iter;
        cout << "grp1 - " << sm[1].str() << ",   grp2 - " << sm[2].str() << endl; 
        matches++;
        ++iter; 
    }
    cout << "Matches: " << matches << endl; 
}
```

Output:

```
grp1 - foo,   grp2 - 12
grp1 - bar,   grp2 - 456
grp1 - b:az,   grp2 - 0
Matches: 3
```

The regex - see its demo - matches

- `([^,]+?)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than a comma, as few as possible
- `:`  - a colon
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 2: one or more digits.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Urkx9H/1).

Comment: I was using https://regexr.com/6bu5s and somehow it showed both the group correctly

Comment: While we are at it, does `sm[1].str()` instantiate string ? if yes, can we avoid it ?

Comment: @ART https://regexr.com/6bu5s says ERROR. No idea how it works there, I prefer regex101.com. Also, regex is all about *strings*, so no idea what you mean by avoiding a string.

Comment: okay I too will use regex101.com now. I meant can we print both the capture groups using iterator only ? I read somewhere in SO that `sm.str()` instantiates the string and to improve performance it should be avoided.

Comment: @ART I do not think it is possible.